# JQuery POSTing with buttons values, returning input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, post

Hey guys and gals I'm having some major issues trying to get my application to work. I've been trying to hack through this and am missing the very first part which is sending the correct input value (button value) to get the ball rolling, I'm sure this is something simple but I've been having an issue getting it working. I'd appreciate it if someone could pick out the error(s) to help me along.

This is extremely easy to do in PHP, but since this is a standalone offline 
app I cannot use PHP =( I need to do all my fetching and parsing in JQuery
or Javascript....

We start with a very basic form with some buttons that have unique values.

```
<form>

<fieldset>
<legend>Select Orders</legend>

<table id='master'></table>

  </div> <!-- end input1 -->
    <div>
     <button name="select" type="submit" id="btnLoad" value="load">Refresh</button>
     <button name="select" type="submit" id="btnJson" value="down">Download JSON</button>
     <button name="select" type="submit" id="btnView" value="view">View/Enter</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

which triggers this function

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {

        /* what obj are we recieving?
        $.each($(this), function(index, obj) {
            console.log('Index: ' + index + ' Obj: '+ obj);
            // returns this B/S: Index: 0 Obj: [object HTMLFormElement]
        });
        */

        // $this.button.val() never makes it through?
        queryJsonServer($(this), "class/");
        return false;
    });
});
```

I've tried things like

```
var button = $(this).attr("value");
var button = $('button').attr("value"); // ends up with the first buttons value,
                                        // but never the selected or $(this).val()

$('button').click(function() {          // which WILL console.log the buttons val,
  console.log($(this).val());           // but will not let me turn it into a var?
  return false;                         // ALSO this looks like it only reads the
});                                     // value the SECOND click?
```

The **Mission** here is to send the buttons value as a $_POST type over to a parser which will return the appropriate JSON array to be parsed, or to be stored in a Local SQLite DB.

Either way, here's the full code of the page, could someone please give me a hand, or if I need to clarify please let me know.

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    var_export($_POST);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
     <title> </title>

     <script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
     <script> google.load('jquery', '1.7.1'); </script>

     <script>
        $(function(){
            $("form").submit(function() 
            {

                /* what obj are we recieving?
                $.each($(this), function(index, obj) {
                    console.log('Index: ' + index + ' Obj: '+ obj);
                    // returns this B/S: Index: 0 Obj: [object HTMLFormElement]
                });
                */

                $('button').click(function() {
                    var state = $(this).val();
                    return true;
                });

                // state is undefined. L29
                console.log(state);

                // $this.button.val() never makes it through?
                queryJsonServer($(this), state, "class/");
                return false;
            });

            // query json server for
            function queryJsonServer(form, state, path) 
            {

                // on first return or refresh inputs will be returrned
                var view    = $('input[name="orders"]:checked').val();
                var url     = path + "json.php?" + state; // status = button.val()
                var state   = $(this).attr("value"); // ends up class/json.php?undefined

                // we have data, lets post to json parser and 
                $.getJSON(url, view, function(data) 
                {
                     $('form').unbind('submit').trigger('submit');

                    var items = [];

                        switch(state)
                        {
                            case 'load' : 

                                $.each(data, function(index, obj) { 
                                    items.push('<tr>');
                                    $.each(obj, function(key, val) { 
                                      items.push((key == "report_number") 
                                      ? '<td class="check" ><input type="checkbox" name="' + val + '" /></td><td><label class="caps" for="'+ key +'">'+ key.replace("_", " ") +'</label><input disabled="disabled" type="text" id="' + key + '" value="' + val + '" /></td>' 
                                      : '<td><label class="caps" for="'+ key +'">'+ key.replace("_", " ") +'</label><input disabled="disabled" type="text" id="' + key + '" value="' + val + '" /></td>')
                                    }); 
                                    items.push('</tr>');
                                });

                                $('<div/>', {
                                    'class': 'jsonOutput',
                                    html: items.join('')
                                  }).appendTo('#master');

                              break;

                            case 'down' : 
                              // populate SQLite Database
                              break;

                            case 'view' : 

                                $.each(data, function(index, obj) { 
                                    items.push('<tr>');
                                    $.each(obj, function(key, val) { 
                                      items.push('<td><label class="caps" for="'+ key +'">'+ key.replace("_", " ") +'</label><input disabled="disabled" type="text" id="' + key + '" value="' + val + '" /></td>')
                                    }); 
                                    items.push('</tr>');
                                });

                                $('<div/>', {
                                    'class': 'jsonOutput',
                                    html: items.join('')
                                  }).appendTo('#master');

                              break;

                            default: 
                              return false; 
                              break;
                        }

                });
            }
        });
     </script>

    <style type="text/css">
     p, ul {width:100%; text-align:left;font-size:80%;}
     .reports_box {width:auto; padding:25px 20px 20px 20px;border:1px solid #91bce6;background-color:#eff5fb;}
     .inputs {width:300px; font-size:15px;padding:5px;}
     .check input {padding:0 !important;}
     .caps {text-transform:capitalize;}
     #reports_list td, #reports_list tr {padding:10px 0 10px 2px;color:#34567b;}
    </style>

    </head>

 <body>


<div class="reports_box">
    <form id='submit'>

    <fieldset>
    <legend>Select Orders</legend>

    <table id='master'></table>

      </div> <!-- end input1 -->
        <div>
         <button name="select" type="submit" id="btnLoad" value="load">Refresh</button>
         <button name="select" type="submit" id="btnJson" value="down">Download JSON</button>
         <button name="select" type="submit" id="btnView" value="view">View/Enter</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    </form>
</div> <!-- end reports_box -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your problem is scope. Your state variable is local and does nothing outside the click function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block form submission unless triggered by a button.

When form submission is triggered by a button:

1. Use $(form).[serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize the form
2. add "&select=ButtonValue" to the serialized string
3. Use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to send a get request to your server page and get a JSON object back.

FINAL EDIT: Here's a working fiddle where I use serialize correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/YYZGG/5/

(When using the code change the form action to your correct page)

Comment: I tried ironing out the errors in your code David, but am unable to get it working, can you take a look? http://pastie.org/3422710

Comment: That's what I get for just trying to write out code blind when I KNOW I'm prone to lots of errors.  Let me play with it some more.

Comment: Thank you Dave for taking the time with me, I appreciate it more than you imagine.

Comment: Okay give the fiddle a look, see if it helps.

Comment: One last thing, since I'm trying to call back the json to my current page, I noticed that I'm going offsite because of `action=''` is there a good way to just return the get contents without leaving?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7976/discussion-between-ehime-and-dave)

Comment: +1 for serialize(), a very convenient method to collect form data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
        $("form").submit(function() 
        {
            var state;

            /* what obj are we recieving?
            $.each($(this), function(index, obj) {
                console.log('Index: ' + index + ' Obj: '+ obj);
                // returns this B/S: Index: 0 Obj: [object HTMLFormElement]
            });
            */

            $('button').click(function() {
                state = $(this).val();
                return true;
            });

            // state is NOW DEFINED
            console.log(state);

            // $this.button.val() never makes it through?
            queryJsonServer($(this), state, "class/");
            return false;

             .......................
```

Also, if having trouble getting the right values, try:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

EDIT:

Are you sure it should'nt just be:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
            var state = e.target.value;
            console.log(state);
---------
```

Comment: `state` still returns `undefined` =(

Comment: Are you sure you are doing the right thing when bindig a click handler to a button, expecting to get the value, inside the submit function ? Seems strange to me.

Comment: No, binding a click handler to the buttons inside the submit() handler won't do anything.

Comment: It's probably not the right way, its just what I was trying to put together, the above edit returned undefined also though

Answer (score 0):

Why does your submit not include a post inside it?  The method your using is `GET` that's why it's not a `POST`, either use `.submit()` and `.post()` together or just use an entire different approach working all together using GET and `.click()` functions, but here's an example of what using `.post()` looks like:

```
<script>
  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {

/* stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault(); 

/* get some values from elements on the page: */
var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( 'action' );

/* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
$.post( url, { s: term },
  function( data ) {
      var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
      $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: After using serialize(), he'll then need to use $.extend() to add the appropriate { select:"buttonValue" } object to the serialized form.

Comment: Could you both elaborate? I'm not sure if I understand your methodology. Thanks greatly.

Comment: #1 i don't know why `.post()` isn't being used here if thats whats trying to be accomplished.

Comment: Because the return is always json, I _thought_ this was the proper way to do it?

Comment: Then why don't you set the `.post( {dataType: JSON} )` ?

Comment: `.post` is fine, I'm just confused as to how to do it compared to what I"m doing?

Comment: If you're not using `.post()` why are you using `.submit()` ?

Comment: I was trying to force post origionally and got mixed up somewhere I think? I've tried revising this to work a few times and I keep leaving things in as I add more. :(